# How to get a percentage of grouped values over a period of time (at the hour scale) in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset containing the duration (in minutes) of occupancy events over a period of 1 hour in my rooms:

```
 #   room  date                duration
---  ----  ------------------- --------
 0   A1    2022-01-01 08:00:00       30
 1   A1    2022-01-01 10:00:00        5
 2   A1    2022-01-01 16:00:00       30
 3   A1    2022-01-02 10:00:00       60
 4   A1    2022-01-02 16:00:00       60
...
```

My date column is linked to a date table in which I have:

```
 #   datetime             year month monthName day dayOfWeek dayName  hour
---  -------------------  ---- ----- --------- --- --------- -------- ----
...
 k   2022-01-01 08:00:00  2022     1   January   1         5 Saturday    8
k+1  2022-01-01 09:00:00  2022     1   January   1         5 Saturday    9
...
 n   2022-03-01 22:00:00  2022     3     March   1         1  Tuesday   22
```

I am trying to retrieve the following percentage: `duration/timeperiod` through a measure. The idea behind using a measure is :

- Being able to use a time slicer and see my percentage being updated
- Using, for example, a bar chart with my date hierarchy, and being able to see a percentage in my different level of hierarchy (datetime -> year -> month -> dayOfWeek -> hour)

### Attempt

My idea was to create a first measure that would return the number of minutes between the first and the last date **currently** chosen. Here is what I came up with:

```
Diff minutes = DATEDIFF(
  FIRSTDATE( 'date'[date] ),
  LASTDATE( 'date'[date] ),
  MINUTE
)
```

The idea was then to create a second measure that would divide the SUM of the durations by the `Diff minutes`' measure:

```
My rate = DIVIDE(
  SUM( 'table'[duration] ),
  [Diff minutes]
)
```

[image]

I currently face a few issues:

- The slicer is set to `(2022-01-02 --> 2022-01-03)` and if I check in a matrix, I have datetime between 2022-01-02 0:00:00 and 2022-01-03 23:00:00, but my measure returns 1440 which is the number of minutes in a day but not in my selected time period
- The percentage is also wrong unfortunately. Let's take the example that I highlighted in the capture. There are 2 values for the 10h slot, 5min and 60min. But the percentage shows 4.51% instead of 54.2%. It actually is the result of `65/1440`, 1440 being the total of minutes for my whole time period, not my 10h slot.

### Examples

1- Let's say I have a slicer over a period of 2 days `(2022-01-01 --> 2022-01-02)` and my dataset is the one provided before:

- I would have a total duration of 185 minutes (30+5+30+60+60)
- My time period would be 2 days = 48h = 2880 minutes
- The displayed ratio would be: 6.4% (185/2880)

2- With the same slicer, a matrix with hours and percentage would give me:

```
hour rate
---- -----
   0  0.0%
   1  0.0%
...
   8 25.0% <--- 30 minutes on the 1st of January and 0 minutes on the 2nd
   9  0.0% <--- (5+0)/120
  10 54.2% <--- (5+60)/120
...
  16 75.0% <--- (30+60)/120
```

### Constraints

The example I provided only has 1 room. In practice, there are n rooms and I would like my measure to return the percentage as the mean of all my rooms.

Would it be possible ? Have I chosen the right method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime, I think I found a simpler and easier way to do it.

First, I added a new column to my date table, that seems dubious but is actually helpful:

```
minutes = 60
```

[image]

This allows me to get rid of the DATEDIFF function. My rate measure now looks like this:

```
My rate = DIVIDE(
    SUM( table[duration] ),
    [Number of minutes],
    0
)
```

Here, I use the measure `Number of minutes` which is simply a SUM of the values in the `minutes` column. In order to provide accurate results when I have multiple rooms selected, I multiplied the number of minutes by the number of rooms:

```
Number of minutes = COUNTROWS( rooms ) * SUM( 'date'[minutes] )
```

This now works perfectly with my date hierarchy!

Answer (score 1):

The DateDiff function you have created should work, I have tested it on a report and when I select some dates, it gives me the difference between the first and last selected dates.

Make sure your slicer is interacting with the measure.

Comment: You were right, I managed to make it work with my date hierarchy. Thanks! I still have some issues unfortunately. I updated my question. Do you have an idea on how I could make my measure work ?